# How to make my android app display a specific facebook post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on multi users android app and I was wondering if there any method to display a specific facebook post inside the app and when the users click on the post he'll be directed to the facebook app then he can "like or share .. that post" and go back to my app

I've been searching a couple of week for method to do that but I can't find any method to do it. If you know any method to do it please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for the same answer myself.
Ended up in sending the link of the post to my app, along with the post-text and image if any. Display the post and image according to you will and redirect the user to the link on click on either the image or the text. If the Facebook app is installed on the device, it will automatically ask you if you need to go to the app. You can design the app to show the image and text one below another to achieve the (near fb) style you need.
This is just a workaround to achieve the feature. I could not find a solution to achieve embedding post in android, the way it can be achieved on the web